# pexpect responses includes echos of requests with <cr>

Tags: shell, python-2.7, pexpect

I have used `pexpect` and `sendline` before, but this time I am running a longer command with *pipes* and *wild card*, see below:

```
commandToRun='/bin/bash -c "/var/scripts/testscripts//extract -o | tail -3"'
returnedString = sendLine(commandToRun)
```

my class which has the sendLine function looks pretty much like this:

```
    self.connection = pexpect.spawn('%s %s' % (protocol, host))
    self.connection.setecho(False)
    self.connection.setwinsize(300, 300)
```

But when I was running the code, I saw that the `returnedString` not only includes the response it also includes the request as well.

So if I print `returnedString`, it look like this:

```
bin/bash -c "/var/scripts/testscripts//extract -o | tail -3"<cr>
100<cr>
102<cr>
103<cr>
```

*Why does the response includes the request in the same buffer?*
I have already set `setecho(False)` and it does not help!

EDIT: (correct fix) I have to manually remove all  from the response and remove the request as well. so setecho(False) still does nothing!

Comment: what is `sendLine()`? spawn.sendline() method returns number of bytes written

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I edited the code above!

Comment: could you provide a minimal (it executes just one command) complete (it can be run  standalone) example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, that would be hard since I am running the command on a machine I can not share. The question is simple? why is request echoed in the response? and why does it include <cr> carrier return-charecter in the echo?

Comment: The problem (most probably) is in your code, so showing it might help. You don't need to share any machine. Does the problem persist with `"/bin/bash -c 'ls | tail -3'"` command? Do you know the difference between `.logfile_read`/`_send`? What is protocol? Where is the code that returns the string?

Comment: Hey there, I am facing the same problem as you.... Found any answer to this?

Comment: @abarik, Unfortunately I have not found a real solution to this problem. What I have done is instead to remove all < CR> and <CR >from the response first and then remove the request from the response as well. then finally you are left only with the response!

Comment: @theAlse, Thanks... I actually never faced a problem with getting <cr> in the output, but faced a problem where I thought my setecho=False doesn't seem to work.... for me, the cmd (sendline) would appear in the output (print self.connection.before). All I did was strip it off just like you are doing... Any case, it would be good to know that even though setecho doesn't work, but in case you are logging, use logfile_read, instead of logfile (http://code.google.com/p/cisco-ios-cli-automation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this myself. (turn off echo in response)

```
commandToRun = 'bash -c "less /readfile | tail -4"'
yourConnection.sendLine("stty -echo")
commandResult = yourConnection.sendLine(commandToRun)
self.sendLine("stty echo")
```

So basically, run you command in a shell using '`bash -c`' and then turn of `echo` in the bash.